# Can First Order Logic Express Cardinal Numbers

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

More specifically, is it possible for two models $M$ and $N$ whose domains' sizes are $\aleph_2$ and $\aleph_3$ respectively to be elementarily equivalent (in first order language)?

What about infinitary logic?

Comment: Lowenhiem-Skolem

Answer (score 6):

For first-order logic, the answer is that **cardinality is largely undetectable**: the [Lowenheim-Skolem theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) say that for any theory $T$ in a language $L$ which has an infinite model and any infinite cardinal $\kappa\ge\vert L\vert$, there is a model of $T$ of cardinality $\kappa$.

That said, there are some interesting nuances:

- The cardinality of the language is quite important. It is *not* necessarily true that if $\aleph_0\le\vert\mathcal{A}\vert<\kappa$ then there is a $\mathcal{B}$ of cardinality $\kappa$ with $\mathcal{A}\equiv\mathcal{B}$.

  - *Specifically, think about an infinite binary tree, in a language rich enough to talk about levels of the tree, equipped with a predicate naming each path. You can show that the theory of this structure has no uncountable models of size $<2^{\aleph_0}$, so if the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) fails we get a "gap" in possible cardinalities. I believe there is also a ZFC-provable example, which I'll add once I remember it.*
- When we look at *two cardinals at once*, things get very complicated indeed. Suppose we have a structure $\mathcal{A}$ with a unary predicate symbol $U$ such that $\vert\mathcal{A}\vert=\aleph_2$ and $\vert U^\mathcal{A}\vert=\aleph_1$. Must $\mathcal{A}$ have an elementary substructure $\mathcal{B}$ with $\vert\mathcal{B}\vert=\aleph_1$ and $\vert U^\mathcal{B}\vert=\aleph_0$? [This also pushes us beyond the usual axioms of set theory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27s_conjecture)

---

For infinitary logic, things are a bit more finicky.

On the one hand, we do have a weak analogue of Lowenheim-Skolem: if $L$ is a countable language and $\varphi$ is *a single $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence* in that language, then every model of $\varphi$ has a countable substructure also satisfying $\varphi$.

*(Incidentally, a slightly weaker version of this - where we just demand some countable model of $\varphi$, not necessarily a substructure of the starting model - has a very silly proof via [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)): given $\mathcal{A}\models\varphi$ uncountable, note that a $Col(\omega,\vert\mathcal{A}\vert)$-generic extension of the universe satisfies "$\varphi$ has a countable model," which is $\Sigma^1_2$ and hence holds already by [Shoenfield absoluteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield's_absoluteness_theorem).)*

But beyond that things are quite complicated. Here are a couple examples:

- The *full $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ theory* of $\mathcal{R}=(\mathbb{R};0,1,+,\cdot)$ is fully categorical: its only model is $\mathcal{R}$ (up to isomorphism).

  - *HINT: for each bounded set $A$ of rationals there is an $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence $\gamma_A$ saying that $A$ has a least upper bound.*
- The *Hanf number* of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ - the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that if an $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence has cardinality $\kappa$ then it has models of arbitrarily large cardinality - is huge: it's [$\beth_{\omega_1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number).

Comment: While $\beth_{\omega_1}$ is huge, it's not even remotely as large as the smallest [huge cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huge_cardinal), which itself is a [large large large large large cardinal](http://karagila.org/2014/ramsey-cardinals-are-large-large-small-large-cardinals/).

Comment: I'm a little confused about your first interesting nuance. In fact it is true that if $\aleph_0\leq |\mathcal{A}|<\kappa$ and $\kappa\geq |L|$, then there is a $\mathcal{B}$ of cardinality $\kappa$ with $\mathcal{A}\equiv \mathcal{B}$ (just by the usual proof of Löwenheim-Skolem). What I would have expected you to say is it is *not* true that if $\aleph_0\leq \kappa < |L|$, then there is a model of $T$ of cardinality $\kappa$ (and here an easier example is just the theory of a bunch of pairwise distinct constant symbols). But maybe I misunderstood your point.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Note that I don't include the hypothesis $\kappa\ge\vert\ L \vert$ - the easier situation you describe is less surprising. But I did miss a very important point there, so I've edited to include it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, now I understand. Thanks!

Comment: There are also cardinality quantifiers, with $Q^\kappa x\,\varphi(x)$ meaning that $\{t:\varphi(t)\}$ has size at least $\kappa$. Again, it is very little what such quantifiers can say about a different cardinality.